# What's the simplest <script> tag with params

Tags: javascript, script-tag

I want to include a script tag, while providing a parameter to it. This is what I came up with so far

1. Provide a parameter to script URL (cons: generate multiple JS files)

   ```
   <script src="http://example.com/something.js?P=123" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. Hide parameter in script tag (cons: same as #1)

   ```
   <script src="http://example.com/scripts/123/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
3. Google Analytics way (cons: ugly, complicated, global variables)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     var _something = _something || 123;
     (function() {
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.type = 'text/javascript';
       s.src = 'http://example.com/something.js';
       var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);
     })();
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the way the script is executed, depends on how it's called, you can add params like your option 1.

Other ways are:

```
<script params='{"abc": 123}' src="script.js"></script><!-- params is a non standard, non official attr that the script will read -->
```

or

```
<script>var _abc = 123;</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

or even

```
<script src="script.js#abc=123"></script>
```

I have to agree with @outis though: load the same thing for everybody, always, and execute it like you/the client want(s) afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is to define things (functions &c) in the external script but execute nothing. Then have an inline script that calls functions/methods defined in the external script.

```
<script src="http://example.com/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    something(123);
</script>
```

Comment: This still has the same downsides of my #3 (global variables, overly complicated to include), albeit shorter :)

Comment: @pitr: there's no global variable, and calling a function isn't exactly complicated. This approach is the same you'd use in other languages, where the external script is a library and the internal is the program entry point. This is also exactly how JS libraries are used.

Comment: `something()` is in a global namespace, isn't it? Libraries expose their functionality (since that's what they are for) through global variables (e.g `$` or `_`). I, however, don't want to unnecessarily pollute namespace (something I didn't mentioned in my question.)

Comment: @pitr: `something` is in the global namespace (which is actually an object, `window` in the case of browsers; globally defined symbols are properties of the global object), but it's a global function, not a global variable (which are the kind of globals you should avoid, and the only kind of global that have been discussed until now). Global functions (including object constructors) are fine (indeed, necessary); even if you don't use them, the included script will define them unless you wrap the entire script in an anonymous function call.

Comment: ... It's global variables and global state that are problematic. You can minimize the number of global symbols defined by a library by creating a namespace (which, in JS, is just an object) that has the functions, constants and variables (which should still be kept to a minimum, to keep global state in check) defined as properties.

Comment: To re-iterate what others said here. A global function in and of itself is not bad (except for namespace pollution and potential name conflicts). However, when that global function uses global variables to keep state, that's when maintenance is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I do this for a cross-sub-domain XHR handler that I have.  I call it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xd.js#subdomain"></script>
```

and then in the script, parse it as such (using jQuery):

```
$('script').each(function(){
    if((src = this.src).indexOf('xd.js') < 0){ return; }
    xds = src.substr(src.indexOf('#') + 1).split(',');

    // do stuff with xds
});
```

Comment: not what I was looking for, as it requires jQuery code in different location, but the idea (similar to @Rudie) is what I will probably end up going for. Thanks!

Comment: The jQuery piece is identical to 'document.getElementsByTagName('script')'

Comment: I wasn't talking about jQuery dependency, but the fact that there is two locations that the code is at, essentially.

Comment: What do you mean it requires jQuery in another location?

Comment: your second piece of code (employing jQuery or not) will be positioned far from the first, thus dropping maintainability

Comment: still don't follow you.  The 2nd piece of code is IN the `xd.js` script and is used to process commands sent to it.  In this case, it just pulls out `subdomain` and you can do whatever you want with it.  You could easily pass `foo=bar&bar=foo` and parse that.  The point is, that that snippet looks for arguments sent to THAT script (`xd.js` in this case) and not any others since you can't pull `location.hash` from within the script (you get the location of the window, not the script).

Answer (score 1):

Your first example does not need to generate multiple files. It can be used by JavaScript alone, by detecting `window.location.href` and parsing it (you might find the likes of http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url:485 and http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str:484 helpful in doing this: `var queryString = parse_str(parse_url(window.location.href).query);` ).

However, if you use something like `#P=123` instead of `?P=123`, you won't cause another download of the file by your users, so I'd recommend that instead (in which case change "query" in the above code sample to "fragment").

Another possibility is using the HTML5-reserved data-* attributes, and detecting their values within your script:

```
<script src="http://example.com/something.js" data-myOwnAttribute="someValue" data-anotherCustomAttribute="anotherValue"></script>
```

The script would then detect along these lines:

```
(function () {
    function getScriptParam (attr) {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
            currentScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
        return currentScript.getAttribute('data-' + attr); // in future, could just use the HTML5 standard dataset attribute instead: currentScript.dataset[attr]
    }
    var myOwnAttribute = getScriptParam('myOwnAttribute');
    // ... do stuff here ...
}());
```

The real advantage of Google's ugly API is that it allows developers to drop in that code in the `<head>` of the document (considered proper form), while still acting asynchronously in a cross-browser way. I think they could indeed avoid the global had they combined their dynamic script-tag technique with either of the above approaches.