# wrapping JavaScript tracking code

Tags: javascript

I have following tracking code from Piwik.

```
<!-- Tracking Code --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://example.com/" : "http://example.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script><script type="text/javascript">
try {
  var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 29);
  piwikTracker.trackPageView();
  piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
} catch( err ) {}
</script><noscript><p><img src="http://example.com/piwik.php?idsite=29" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- Tracking Code -->
```

I want to hide following code, so I think I can put this code in some js file, and load it using following code.

But I don't know how can I do it. Help required here.

Secondly, I need to change site id (in above example, is 29), which will be different for different site.

How can I pass site-id to custom file that I will make, and execute above code.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding the code? And what are you hiding it from? For your secondary question, see ["What's the simplest <script> tag with params?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774672/whats-the-simplest-script-tag-with-params/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pkBaseURL = (
    ( "https:" == document.location.protocol )
    ?
    "https://example.com/"
    :
    "http://example.com/");  

var piwik_script = document . createElement ( "script" ) ;
piwik_script . src = pkBaseURL + "piwik.js" ;
document . body . appendChild ( piwik_script ) ;

function track ()
{
  try
  {
    var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", piwik_page_id);
    piwikTracker.trackPageView();
    piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
  } catch( err ) {}
}

piwik_script . addEventListener ( "load", track );
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this in piwik_loader.js:

```
    var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://example.com/" : "http://example.com/");
    var piwik_js = document.createElement('script');
    piwik_js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    piwik_js.setAttribute("src", pkBaseURL + "piwik.js");
    var executor = function ()
    {
       try {
      var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", piwik_page_id);
      piwikTracker.trackPageView();
      piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
      } catch( err ) {}

    }

    piwik_js.onreadystatechange= function ()
    {
       if (this.readyState == 'complete')
       executor();
    }
    piwik_js.onload = executor;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertBefore(piwik_js, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].firstChild);
```

And this into your html file:

```
<!-- Tracking Code --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> var piwik_page_id = '29'; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="piwik_loader.js"></script>    

<noscript><p><img src="http://example.com/piwik.php?idsite=29" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- Tracking Code -->
```

Comment: That will document.write the script element that loads the external resources after the current script element … which means they won't load until **after** the `try` block is run, so the objects that the `try` block depends up on won't exist and it will just break.

Comment: Can you recheck the solution?

Comment: It is worse. A script element is still created, but it is never added to the document.

Comment: Edit: I've just added a line that appends the newly created script element to the head element, so that its content gets executed, before the try-catch block.

Comment: Nope, something still missing.

Comment: How about now? :) It creates a new script element, inserts it on top in head and attaches an event which is executed on piwik.js load. So when the file is loaded it should do the piwik tracking.

Comment: Well, I tested this on FF4, IE7&8, Chrome, Opera. All seem to work.

Comment: readystate change only works in IE on script elements, and won't always fire a `complete` state (something to do with loading from the network or the cache IIRC).

Comment: thats why its piwik_js.onload after it.